# Wordpress white blank page after resizing Google Compute Engine Persistent Disk

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

Help, I resized the boot disk of my Google Cloud Instance and now my Bitnami Wordpress site is inaccessible.  I've reset the instance and restarted all services.  I can ftp into the site and see everything there, but I get a blank screen in Google and an http:500 error when accessing my site now.  The wp-admin is also inaccessible.

Comment: have you checked file permissions?

Comment: I had to resize the file system and restart my instance and it worked.